# NanxyFX RequiresAnyClaim(...) Failing With Valid Credentials

Tags: nancy

I am utilizing the `NancyModule` extensions to check claims in my endpoints.

When I debug my endpoint, I can see that the authenticated user has the valid claim that I am looking for. (This is shown in the screenshot below).

In the screenshot, I am debugging an endpoint with a user that has `Vendor Admin`, and the endpoint requires that it either be an `Admin` or `Vendor Admin`.

Execution does not continue past this check and a `HTTP 401 Unauthorized` is returned.

I have additionally tried to see if I could use the `OnError()` hook in my bootstrapper, but it does not hit following this call.

Any ideas why this (or any of the other extension methods, `Requires Authentication`,`RequiresClaims`,etc) is not working?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot it looks like there could be an issue with the way Nancy is trying to match your user's claims (since you appear to have a non-null user and non-null claim enumeration).

Assuming you're using the standard Nancy.Security user claims, then the Nancy code for claims check is:

```
///From Nancy.Security.UserIdentityExtensions
public static bool HasAnyClaim(this IUserIdentity user, IEnumerable<string> requiredClaims)
    {
        return
            user != null
            && user.Claims != null
            && requiredClaims.Any(claim => user.Claims.Contains(claim, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
```

Check the datatype of your Claims object in your implementation of IUserIdentity and verify it will return true with:

```
requiredClaims.Any(claim => user.Claims.Contains(claim, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```